# A password dialog for my Android app

Tags: android, dialog, passwords, onresume

My MAIN Activity is a password dialog (@android:style/Theme.Dialog). Upon successful authentication, it launches the application page (also an Activity), and calls finish() on itself. Its important to me that the password dialog launch standalone and not float on top of the application page.

Everything is fine the first time. However when the user leaves the app by pressing Home, and then returns back by clicking the app icon on the "desktop", the password dialog does not launch again (since onResume is called). If the user presses the Back button to leave the application, and then relaunches the app, the password dialog is called.

The more I think about this, the less elegant my solutions are becoming! I hope there is a simple solution here. As I write this, I tried the option of not calling finish() on the password dialog, but that didn't change a thing.

Comment: Why is it important the login dialog be standalone and not float on top of the application?

Comment: Some of the fields in the main app page would be visible since the floating password dialog only occupies a small portion of the screen.

Comment: Ahhh I see, blurring would not suffice? http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/blurring-dimming-background-windows-when-dialog-is-displayed-t10447.html

Answer (score 2):

In your onResume() method (when resuming from say a "home" button press), make a call to login again. Sorry for such a short answer, but that sounds like the most reasonable solution :).

Comment: Thank you for responding. There are 2 issues with calling the login/password dialog from onResume:
- the very first time the dialog will be presented twice, confusing the user (yes, one could use a boolean to avoid this)
- on subsequent times, the password dialog will appear over the application main page, and some of the information visible could be confidential

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I decided to use a timer in onResume(). If the last time a password has been requested is over 30 seconds ago, then I show the dialog again. And yes I am using blurring (thanks Jack!).